# Plotting bar charts with resampled data and width=1 and how to avoid 'Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays to Timestamp'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, error-handling

I'm getting the following error error when trying to plot a bar chart with resampled data:

```
FutureWarning: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays to Timestamp is deprecated, will be removed in a future version.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * self.freq`
  dx = [convert(x0 + ddx) - x for ddx in dx]
```

My code:

```
plt.bar(df.index, df.tally, width=1)
plt.show()
```

This returns the graph as expected but with the `FutureWarning`.

[Plot with `width=1` returns graph as expected but error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvD5a.png)

`df` is resampled data, like below. It occurs whether I use weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly and I assume any frequency.

Date    tally
2015-01-31  7
2015-02-28  4
2015-03-31  2
2015-04-30  2

Removing `width=1` removes the error but returns a useless barplot with near invisible thin white lines.

[Plot without `width=1` returns thin white lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRjmG.png)

The plot appears like this, I believe, because the data is being plotted on only a single day for each month, or whatever frequency. These tallies are therefore tiny on an axis with 5 years of data points - not a problem for scatterplots.

I don't understand why I'm getting the error. Where am I adding integers to Timestamps?

Maybe there is a better method for plotting resampled data as a time series.